# no visible @iterface CDVViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

The following codes give me "No visile @iterface CDVViewController" compilation error:

```
@implementation MainViewController (CDVViewController)
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webView.opaque = NO;
     return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
}

@end
```

[image: The error message is here]

This error happens when I compile [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) within an application program built for ios. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

import statement in on your class

```
#import "CDVViewController.h"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that my xcode complain that CDVViewController.h file not found.

Comment: i don't know cordova , but your error says , the class not imported in the current class

Answer (score 1):

To resolve CDVViewController.h file not found issue, follow below steps:

1) Select your  in Xcode "TARGETS".

2) Go to "Build Settings" tab.

3) Search "Header Search Paths"

4) Double click and add this path: $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include

5) Now clean the Project, restart the Xcode.

6) Able to make the "Build", and  "Archive".

7) You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please add "UIWebViewDelegate" in the CDVViewController.h

```
@interface CDVViewController : UIViewController <CDVScreenOrientationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate>
```